# Resize Textarea resize from edge

Tags: jquery, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable, jquery-resizable

I have following using Jquery and somehow I can resize it the right bottom corner  where i see a resize icon . On side edges it shows <--> for resize but I cant stretch it from edge to resize ?What can be wrong ?

```
<div class="dragDiv" id="dragDiv">

    <div id="header" class="ui-widget-header handler"><img src="Styles/move_icon.jpg" align="top">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>

<div style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <textarea  style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Arial;font-size:11pt;border: 1px;color: white;" id="Text" name="Text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Mark" onclick="MarkImage()" style="height: 20px;" />
</div>
```

```
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


$("#dragDiv").resizable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of

```
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
```

And do this instead.

```
$("#dragDiv").resizable({
 handles: 'e,w,s,n,se'
});
```

Comment: Cool ! Worked .... Is there any way to limit minimum height and width on re sizable div so people cant make it smaller or larger than some particular specified size ?

Comment: You can add the `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` options so the code looks like   `$("#dragDiv").resizable({
     handles: 'e,w,s,n,se',
     maxHeight:200,
     maxWidth:200
    });`